# Liferay IDE Alternatives

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am using Liferay Developer Studio for theme development and as a frontend developer, I am not impress with the tool's performance.

Below are few reasons I am looking for alternative IDE, compatible for Liferay development.

1. It occupies more than 75% of the memory
2. It slower down the whole system
3. I cannot use chat application while running IDE as to switch from one app to another takes irrelevant time
4. I use to build theme through CLI. Sometime I need to close the IDE or else it gives runtime error and doesn't build the theme.

I am sure there are many others too faced same issues, which actually makes the development slower. This question is not against the Liferay of course, it's a great enterprise level CMS tool. But yes looking for alternate IDE with best compatibility for the purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Gulp** and **Yo** to generate, build and deploy your theme or layout  , and you can use **Notepad ++** as editor.

Please refere to those links :

1 - [LIFERAY theme generator](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/themes-generator)

2 - [Gulp Tasks](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/theme-gulp-tasks)

Comment: Yes that's a good suggestion. But I am using LR IDE from 4 years and now handy with it. If we use Gulp/Grunt and Yo will faster the workflow but again Notepad++ is not as rich in terms of features that LDS provides. I don't think it can replace completely.

Comment: Are you using freemarker or velocity as template engine ?

Comment: So you're familiar with Liferay IDE but don't want to use it? There's no "drop in replacement", but Liferay is agnostic to the development environment you use. Feel free to use IntelliJ Idea, Netbeans, Notepad(++), vi or emacs - all are fine. As NeptuneZ says, for Frontend stuff, gulp&yo and related tools are the way to go. If IDE occupies 75% of your memory, consider upgrading your development computer with more memory - it might be cheaper than changing the familiar development environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any IDE you want. The only one difference between LiferayIDE and others IDEs is you can avoid using BladeCLI by hands. 
And nothing can stop you to use another IDE, build you project with maven or gradle and then continue to develop.

If you are a front-end developer you really should use Gulp and Yo. First time you'll feel yourself confused a bit, but after short period of time you'll understand all benefits.